# Animation on textviews placed inside a linear layout

Tags: android, animation, view, textview, scaleanimation

I need to implement an animation on text views which are placed inside the layout,

My requirement is, 
I need to show Ist three text views on the screen

```
"Title1(left of the screen)  Title2(center)   Title3(right of the screen)".
```

when user click on the text `'Title3'` i need to show

```
 Title2(at left)   Title3(at center) and Title4(at right).
```

and then when we click on `'Title4'` it will show

`Title3(at left)    Title4(at center) and Title1(at right)` like a rotation. How can we implement this kind of animation,

This is my code,

in onclick() i have called below lines for scale animation,

```
tv3.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.right_to_left));
tv2.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.right_to_left));
tv1.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.right_to_left));
tv3.getAnimation().setAnimationListener(flipperAnimationListener);
```

and my animation listener is given below

```
flipperAnimationListener = new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                changeTab();
            }
        };
```

Comment: Do you mean card flip animation like this http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html ?

Comment: No not like that, its scale animation, that means when we click on "page3" "page1" will hide and "page2", "page3" and "page4" will show in the screen and so on.

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: After animation the text is changed, so there is a lag.

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you use ViewPager? It contains what you want.

Here's an example: https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSFjdgbbZGqUzaWTmm7Rvj4OtRx2oWnHfBYghwwmRIoStKLnzfLAg

This is an example of ViewPager: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

To activate "PagerTitleStrip" just override getPageTitle:

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
return "Title " + position;
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right,already I tried that, but i need a circular animation,
that means after page4 i need page1 as next tab.

is there any method for that??